# What are the types and prices of Licences available?

Tags: canonical, license

what are the types of licence that we can get for the Ubuntu server and if any of the editions costs money how much would that be around?

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu server itself is free.

you might want to pay for support contracts, or additional maintanance tools (Like Landscape). For that sort of info, you should visit canonical.com

Answer (score 1):

> what are the types of licence that we can get for the Ubuntu server and if any of the editions costs money how much would that be around?

**Free** (both as beer and as freedom) with community support.

Others licences with paid support refer to the [Canonical Enterprises Services](http://www.canonical.com/enterprise-services) page.

Answer (score 1):

It's only available under [the licenses that Ubuntu is available under](http://www.ubuntu.com/about/about-ubuntu/licensing). These are non-negotiable en-masse.

As for money, all the default licenses are free, many with non-monetary conditions (eg conditions if you wish to redistribute). You can add non-free software under difference licenses if you wish... But that's up to you. The components that make up Ubuntu Server are all free.